# error when use onKeylistener

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to test how to use setOnKeyListener, and every time eclipse suggests to use

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

but i dont want to use this Listener, I want to use

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

And every time i try to use the latter, eclipse gives me an error, and i dont know how should fix this.

Any suggestions??

Comment: I think its case of wrong import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you imported

```
DialogInterface.OnKeyListener
```

instead of

```
View.OnKeyListener
```